# Stack of records theorem from Allan Pollack and Guillemin differential topology.(Q.1.4.7)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have found 3 links that contain the solution of this question, but in 2 links I have difficulties in understanding some parts of the solution.

**For the first link:**

The link is given below:

http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~simic/Spring09/Math213/final.213.09.soln.pdf

The theorem proof is given in Q.2 on the third page. but I have a difficulty in understanding the last part of the first line, which says:" then $f^{-1}(y)$" is a discrete subset of $M$"

I could not understand this part, could anyone explain it for me please?

**For the second link**

The link is given below:

http://www.math.utah.edu/~keenan/manifoldsnotes.pdf

The proof is given in page 35, but I do not understand the following parts of the solution:

1- why he said that $f^{-1}$ is compact, may be he considered that $f^{-1}$ is continuous and he uses the theorem that say that:"A continuous image of a compact set is compact", but then why he considered that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

2- why he said that $f^{-1}$ is finite?

3- why $f$ is a local diffeomorphism?

Could anyone help me understanding those questions?

**I will update the question with the third link and my questions about it later.**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Regular Level Set Theorem, since $y$ is a regular value of $f:X\to Y$, we have that $f^{-1}(y)$ is smooth embedded submanifold of $X$ of codimension (in $X$) equal to the dimension of $Y$.  Since $\dim{X}=\dim{Y}$, we have that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a $0$-dimensional submanifold.  Since $f$ is continuous, the preimage of any closed set is closed.  So $f^{-1}(y)$ is closed, and hence compact, since it's a closed subset of the compact set $X$.

**Begin Edit-**
$f^{-1}(y)$ is discrete since it's a $0$-dimensional manifold.  Since it's compact and discrete it must be finite.  Indeed, if it was infinite, then it would contain a limit point.  Hence every neighborhood of said point would contain other points in the set contradicting discreteness.  Hence $f^{-1}(y)=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$.
**-End Edit**

It's a local diffeomorphism about each $x_j\in f^{-1}(y)$ by the inverse function theorem (since $y$ is a regular value $df_{x_j}$ has full rank at each $x_j$).

The remainder of the proof is just chasing open sets until you have one small enough with all the desired properties.

Comment: What do you mean by has a full rank?

Comment: @hopefully, $df_{x_j}$ is a linear map between tangent spaces, so "full rank" means that it is invertible (since $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension).

Comment: I do not know what theorem of linear algebra says this, could you please mention the theorem for me? thanks in advance

Comment: If a linear map $T:V\to W$ is of full rank, then it's injective if $\dim{V}\leq\dim{W}$ and surjective if $\dim{V}\geq\dim{W}$.  If $\dim{V}=\dim{W}$ then it's bijective and hence invertible.

Comment: I think you did not answer the first question in the first link>>>>>>why he concluded directly from the first part of line 1 that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a discrete subset of $M$?

Comment: Could you please recommend a good book to be a reference for me for linear algebra?

Comment: Could you reference a book for me for the proof of this part " If$ dimV=dimW $then it's bijective and hence invertible."?

Comment: I think that there is no theorem named by "Regular Level Set Theorem" in this book ..... correct?

Comment: @hopefully, I edited my answer to include that portion.  It's a standard compactness argument.  As for a linear algebra resource, I'm partial to "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces" by Paul Halmos.  I also suggest Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" to be understand these topics applied to manifolds.  His exposition is probably the best for the introductory level.

Comment: Why a zero dimensional manifold is discrete?

Comment: What's the definition of a $0$-dimensional manifold?  Also, the regular level set theorem goes by many names.  It's essentially the Inverse/Implicit Function Theorem applied to manifolds.

Comment: Is not the isomorphism in the inverse function theorem means that f and f^{-1]  are continuous? how did you check that  f^{-1}  is continuous?