# Stack of records theorem for manifolds with boundary

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm considering the so called "stack of records" theorem, which states that if $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth function between manifolds of the same dimension, and $M$ is compact, then if $y \in N$ is a regular value of $f$, then $|f^{-1}(y)|$ is finite.

My question is, do we necessarily need $M$ to be boundaryless to conclude that $|f^{-1}(y)|$ is finite? The proofs I often see invoke the inverse function theorem, which to my knowledge doesn't necessarily hold if $M$ has boundary. However, it seems like the result *should* still go through...

One sufficient condition for this would be $|f^{-1}(y)| \subseteq int(M)$ for each regular value $y$ so that the implicit function theorem can be applied, but I was wondering if there was something more general that anybody knows of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931602/stack-of-records-theorem-from-allan-pollack-and-guillemin-differential-topology

Comment: In that conditions, $f^{-1}(y)$ is a dimension zero submanifold of $M$. It is a discrete closed set, but $M$ is compact. so this level set must be finite.

Comment: @YongminPark I think I understand what you are saying. In Milnor, we have that in the case where $M$ has boundary, then if $y$ is a regular value for both $f$ and the restriction $f |_{\partial{M}}$ , then $f^{-1}(y)$ is an $dim(M)-dim(N)$ dimensional manifold. 

Thus, since we are assuming $dim(M)=dim(N)$, this would make $f^{-1}(y)$ a zero dimensional manifold, as you suggest. But how are you concluding that $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite?

Comment: You first need to show that if a manifold $M$ is $0$-dimensional, then it is a discrete space as a topological space. Further, if $M$ is compact, then $M$ is a finite set since any discrete compact topological space is a finite set. Anyway, these are contained in the linked post by Sumanta.

Comment: If you do not require than $df_x\colon T_xM\to T_yN$ is surjective for $x\in\partial M$, then I believe you can construct an example (even with $\dim M=\dim N=1$) with infinitely many preimage points in $M$ approaching $x$ in the boundary. The result you refer to can't apply in this case, since $f|_{\partial M}$ cannot be a submersion because the dimension is too low.

Comment: @TedShifrin Here's what I've gathered: From Lemma 4 in Milnor, if $y$ is a regular value for both $f$ AND $f|_{\partial{M}}$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a $dim(M)-dim(N)$ (=0 in our case) degree manifold. Is this the extra condition you are mentioning?

If that works, then because almost all $y$ are regular values for $f$ and $f|_{\partial{M}}$, then by the arguments given by the commenters above, we can conclude under my conditions that $|f^{-1}(y)|$ is finite for almost all $y$.

Comment: I'm saying that in the equidimensional case, you cannot have a regular value for the restriction to the boundary, unless it's by default, i.e., the preimage lies entirely in the interior. And in that case, as you've noted, the preimage must be finite. Can you give an example, however, where there are infinitely many preimage points, including a boundary point?

Comment: @TedShifrin Just off the top of my head, could you be referring to a function similar to the topologists sine curve by considering the value of the function at the boundary point?

Comment: The smoothly damped one, yes.

Comment: @TedShifrin

Thanks! 'm still a bit confused by your last comment. Are you saying that my conclusion would in fact hold with that extra assumption of $y$ being regular for $f|_{\partial{M}}$, or that this assumption isn't needed in the equidimensional case?

Comment: What we've established is that you have to force the preimage to miss the boundary. Saying $y$ is a regular value of the restriction does accomplish this, as I said.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks again. But now I'm second guessing...why wouldn't the value at the boundary for the example we just constructed be regular?

Comment: Because the derivative has to vanish at the limit point of the sequence.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes.... interesting. Is there a general result that says in this 1 dimensional case that if $|f^{-1}(y)|$ is non finite, then $y$ is attained at the border at which the derivative either vanishes or is not defined....? Interesting that it happens in this example, but could there be others?